# How to join grouped and filtered fields on table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I have this dataset that I want to group by user_id and sum the values by category

| id | user_id | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 30 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 40 |

And I want a select returning a table with one element for user_id with one field for each category value (These are known and can only be 1, 2 or 3)

| user_id | category_1 | category_2 | category_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 40 | 10 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 40 |

The only solution I've found is:

```
select
  r.user_id as user_id,
  rt_c1.value as category_1_value,
  rt_c2.emissions_change_co2e as scope2_co2e_emissions,
  rt_c3.emissions_change_co2e as scope3_co2e_emissions
from tablename as r
join (select 
  rt.user_id
  rt.category as category,
  sum(rt.value) as value
from tablename as rt
group by rt.user_id, rt.category) as rt_c1
on rt_c1.user_id = r.user_id and rt_c1.category = 1
join (select 
  rt.user_id
  rt.category as category,
  sum(rt.value) as value
from tablename as rt
group by rt.user_id, rt.category) as rt_c2
on rt_c2.user_id = r.user_id and rt_c2.category = 2
join (select 
  rt.user_id
  rt.category as category,
  sum(rt.value) as value
from tablename as rt
group by rt.user_id, rt.category) as rt_c3
on rt_c3.user_id = r.user_id and rt_c3.category = 3
```

Comment: Use `Count` function inside your Sub Queries and then Check the same Within the Sub Query by using `Having` Clause or Check with the `ON` Clause or atlast by in the `Where` Clause.

Comment: I'm sorry @Thiyagu I've didn't understand your suggestion :thinking:

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: PostgresSQL actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a simple conditional aggregation

**Example**

```
Select user_id
      ,sum( case when category=1 then value else 0 end) as category_1
      ,sum( case when category=2 then value else 0 end) as category_2 
      ,sum( case when category=3 then value else 0 end) as category_3
 From  YourTable
 Group By user_id
```

Comment: @BrunoLoops Always happy to help

Comment: @BrunoLoops: alternatively you can use `count(*) filter (where category = 1) as category_1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Except that `COUNT(*)` != `SUM(value)`

Comment: I see the SQL Server tag is now gone.

Comment: @MatBailie: a sorry, right: `sum(value) filter (where ...)`